# Critical section in cython

Tags: python, c++, openmp, cython, critical-section

How to handle critical section in cython when using prange in cython?

Is **#pragma omp critical** allowed?

```
for e in prange(num,nogil=True,num_threads=4):
.
.
.
  #pragma omp critical
  cs
.
.
.
end_for
```

Comment: Have you tried it? Did you get any errors?

Comment: #pragma is a preprocesser directive for c compilers. I don't think this will work. However I found this: http://www.perrygeo.com/parallelizing-numpy-array-loops-with-cython-and-mpi.html

Comment: @DavidW can gil work for multi-statement cs...?

Comment: @DavidW: That's what I thought how the GIL works, i.e. every with-gil-block will be executed completely and then only another with-gil-block in another thread can be started. *This is not the case.* See the docs https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/init.html#thread-state-and-the-global-interpreter-lock. Tested it myself as well. Python might execute code in another thread basically after each line. There is no way to prevent this thread switching completely in Python, afaik right now. The openmp solution by Okason is the first clean, simple, and working solution I found.

Comment: @Oli You're right. A lot of the time it isn't an issue - it won't switch threads unless it hits some arbitrary Python code (most likely a destructor or a callback function or something like that) so you're very careful about your Cython code it's probably possible to be certain it won't. But yes - it isn't guaranteed so relying on it is a bad idea! The solution here is good and _much_ safer.

Comment: I've removed the bad advice (which I realise makes your comment not make sense!)

Comment: @DavidW: Ah that "arbitrary Python code" explains the behavior I've seen in my testing. I was wondering why the switching didn't seem consistent regarding runtime like https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.setswitchinterval suggests."Less of an issue"... Well, at least I won't ever trust myself enough to not mess up somewhere and needing weeks to debug later on.

Answer (score 3):

To handle a critical section you can use an openmp lock.
To do this import it using

```
cimport openmp
```

then initialize it

```
cdef openmp.omp_lock_t lock
openmp.omp_init_lock(&lock)
```

and use it this way

```
with nogil, cython.boundscheck(False), cython.wraparound(False):
    for i in parallel.prange(n, schedule = 'static', 
                             num_threads = num_threads):
        .
        .
        .
        openmp.omp_set_lock(&lock)
        cs
        openmp.omp_unset_lock(&lock)
        .
        .
        .
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found another solution with Cython and C++11 instead of openmp like in Okason's answer.

```
cdef extern from "<mutex>" namespace "std" nogil:
    cdef cppclass recursive_mutex:
        pass
    cdef cppclass lock_guard[T]:
        lock_guard(recursive_mutex mm)

cdef recursive_mutex mtx

cdef void someFun() nogil:
    # lock_guard locks the mutex when it is created
    cdef lock_guard[recursive_mutex]* lck = new lock_guard[recursive_mutex](mtx)
    # do something thread-safely
    del lck
    # lock_guard unlocks the mutex when it is deleted

for ii in prange(4, nogil=True, num_threads=2):
    someFun(ii)
```

If we could allocate C++ objects to the stack in Cython we could omit `del lck` and make it a little bit nicer in my opinion; unfortunately Cython doesn't allow this afaik. With the approach above there is a risk of forgetting to unlock, and I think one could just use the mutex directly (with `mtx.lock()` I think) instead of `lock_guard`.

I use a recursive_mutex since a nested/recursive lock is usually required for my use cases. Just as a note.

I just cooked up this solution and I can't say if openmp or C++11 are the recommended way.

**EDIT:** One could use shared pointers to get down to one line and "safer" guaranteed unlocking (add/replace these lines in example above where appropriate):

```
from libcpp.memory cimport shared_ptr, make_shared
[...]
cdef shared_ptr[lock_guard[recursive_mutex]] lck = make_shared[lock_guard[recursive_mutex]](mtx)
```

Not really nice to look at, though.